# Jquery ajax request to flurry gives error Cross-Origin Request Blocked

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using flurry api to receive json data. So I have to call more than one time to flurry url and receive data. But except first request, all the other requests gives this error

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I have created [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hydride/hv3xrjwL/) for this. There you can see the same error.

Here is the code I'm using to recieve data

```
function($) {
    var url = 'http://api.flurry.com/appMetrics/ActiveUsersByMonth?apiAccessCode=DXGSYSYBSK26BZNSJB2X&apiKey=Removed&startDate=2012-01-01&endDate=2012-12-30&country=LK&versionName=1.0&groupBy=MONTHS';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            console.dir(json);
            alert();
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    }).done(function(data) {

        var activeUsers = [];

        $.each( data.day, function( i, item ) {
            var arr = $.map(item, function(el) { return el; });
            activeUsers.push(arr[1]);
        });

        var barChartData = {
            labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"],
            datasets : [
                {
                    fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                    strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                    highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                    highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    data : activeUsers
                }
            ]

        }
        var myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Bar(barChartData, {
            responsive : true
        });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hydride/hv3xrjwL/

Comment: have you tried dataType: 'json' to dataType: 'jsonp',

Comment: Yes. Didn't work. I think jsonp is not supported by the furry api

Comment: then use php to request the service and use it to encode into json. Then you can access that json using ajax in your Javascript.

Comment: I didn't get that. Can you please post sample.

Comment: Did anyone encountered similar errors and got through?

Comment: @Humanlove Thanks for the tip. Finally achieved what I wanted by trying your method. Its totally worked with some additional code. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Human love for the tip. Achived what I wanted by trying this way. Moved my flurry url to php and requested service from there. Then encoded the result in to json. It giving same errors if you didn't set the headers properly.

Server side code:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
$url="http://api.flurry.com/appMetrics/ActiveUsersByMonth?apiAccessCode=DXGSYSYBSK26BZNSJB2X&apiKey=Removed&startDate=2012-01-01&endDate=2012-12-30&country=LK&versionName=1.0&groupBy=MONTHS";
$json=file_get_contents($url);
echo $json;
```

Client side jquery ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "<?php echo base_url("frontpage/monthly_active_count"); ?>"
})
    .done(function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
        var activeUsers = [];

        $.each( data.day, function( i, item ) {
            var arr = $.map(item, function(el) { return el; });
            activeUsers.push(arr[1]);
        });

        var barChartData = {
            labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"],
            datasets : [
                {
                    fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                    strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                    highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                    highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    data : activeUsers
                }
            ]

        }
        var myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Bar(barChartData, {
            responsive : true
        });

    });
```